# Android Gradle - add proguard_rules.pro file to a maven repository

Tags: android, maven, android-gradle-plugin

I've created a project which builds a snapshot to a library, and another project uses this library with maven.

This is my gradle file in the library (i've removed some parts, its pretty long)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    ...
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            consumerProguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), rootDir.absolutePath + '/proguard_debug.pro'
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), rootDir.absolutePath + '/proguard_release.pro'

            consumerProguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), rootDir.absolutePath + '/proguard_release.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
... 
}

apply plugin: 'maven'
apply plugin: 'signing'

afterEvaluate { project ->
    uploadArchives {
           ...
        }
    }

    uploadArchives.dependsOn tasks.findByName("bundleRelease")
}

...
}
```

I generate snapshots using the task uploadArchives, which works fine. 
However, when i import the maven snapshot, the file proguard_release.pro is missing.

```
Warning:Exception while processing task java.io.FileNotFoundException:
.../.../build/intermediates/exploded-aar/.../394-SNAPSHOT/proguard_release.pro 
(No such file or directory)
```

Basically my issue is that i can't see the proguard_rules.pro file when i create a snapshot, it looks like i need another task to preform it.

I tried using *'embedProguard'*, *'mergeDebugProguardFiles'*, *'mergeReleaseProguardFiles'*, but it looks that the proguard_rules.pro doesn't apply to the generated aar.
When i open the aar, i can't see it, and the aar doesn't include the proguard_rules.pro definitions.
[image: aar]